# driving distance calculation mysql

Tags: mysql, geolocation, maps

I have this standard mysql I am using where $latlng is the lat and long the user is inputting. I get the correct  coordinates. Then I use the Haversine formula to get the radius. The output I use to sort in a foreach which is correct until you want 'driving distance'. Any idea to to get the right distance via driving using mysql? Note I can get driving via google distance matrix but in a json return not within the mysql statement I and getting all my data from.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('{$latlng['lat']}') ) * cos( radians( a.lat ) ) *
                        cos( radians( a.lng ) - radians('{$latlng['lng']}') ) + sin( radians('{$latlng['lat']}') ) *
                        sin( radians( a.lat ) ) )
                     ) AS radius
               FROM (
                  SELECT  p.*, pm_lat.meta_value-0.0 AS lat, pm_lng.meta_value-0.0 AS lng
                  FROM $wpdb->posts p
                  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm_lat ON (p.ID=pm_lat.post_id AND pm_lat.meta_key='_location_coordinates_lat')
                  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm_lng ON (p.ID=pm_lng.post_id AND pm_lng.meta_key='_location_coordinates_lng')
                  WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
               ) AS a
               HAVING radius < $radius
               ORDER BY radius ASC
```

Comment: Can you clarify? By "driving distance" do you mean the distance from $latlng to a.lat/a.lng when following roads?  The haversine formula computes the distance to be flown by a disciplined and focused crow, not the distance along rows.

Comment: correct driving on roads. I can get that elsewhere on my page distance matrix but that just returns json I decode. The mysql is where I am pulling in the data in a foreach and sorting my page returns. Since it uses the pure point to point it doesn't match the driving.

Comment: I know the Haversine formula s not going to help with spitting out correct driving distance. Probably going to have to rework the page entirely.

Comment: It wouldn't be terribly hard to write a function `$distance = how_far($start, $end, $route);`  `$route` could have values like "Auto" or "Bicycle" or "Great Circle". The function would have to figure out whether it could use a MySQL-resident table ("Great Circle") or go to an online map service. The function could also cache results (in a MySQL table) to save redundant uses of the map service.